# Multiple Plot in GNUplot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I want to do multiplot or subplot in GNUplot. I have two files that has x1, y1 in two files. I want to have two graphs plotted in GNUplot like a subplot. Suppose I have the following two files

Plot1

12:14:38 10

12:15:38 11

12:16:38 12

12:17:38 15

and another file

Plot2

12:17:38 15

12:18:38 11

12:19:38 12

12:20:38 15

I want to generate two graphs for these two values. How do i do it using GNUplot. Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

If I understand what you are asking, here is the basic syntax:

```
set term png size 600,400
set output 'plot.png'

set multiplot           # engage multiplot mode
set size 1.0,1.0        # sets the size of the first plot
set xdata time          ## these three lines control how gnuplot
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'  ## reads and writes time-formatted data.
set format x '%H:%M:%S' ##

plot 'data1' u 1:2      # plot the first data set

set size 0.4,0.4        # set the size of the second plot in plot units
set origin 0.15,0.5     # set the origin for the second plot in plot units

plot 'data2' u 1:2      # plot the second data set
```

This will plot the second data set as a subfigure.

[image: subfigure plot]

To make two plots in a grid, you can use `set multiplot layout`:

```
set term png size 600,300
set output 'plot.png'

set multiplot layout 1,2        # engage multiplot mode
#set size 1.0,1.0       # sets the size of the first plot
set xdata time          ## these three lines control how gnuplot
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'  ## reads and writes time-formatted data.
set format x '%H:%M:%S' ##
set xtics 120           # make time spacing of 2 minutes

plot 'data1' u 1:2      # plot the first data set 

#set size 0.4,0.4       # set the size of the second plot in plot units
#set origin 0.15,0.5    # set the origin for the second plot

plot 'data2' u 1:2      # plot the second data set 
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ..
  I want two graphs in the same page. Not like the one which you showed. :(. Basically I want two or Four graphs in a single page. Can you please tell me how to do that.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user1667228 -- that's because in gnuplot, its called `multiplot`.  To create a "grid" of plots, you can just do `set multiplot layout 2,2` (for a 2 by 2 grid).  Of course, then you can tweak the position and size of each plot using `origin` and `size` like andyras did in this example, but that's rarely necessary.

Comment: Also, it's good practice to add an `unset multiplot` at the end ... I'm not sure if this is still the case, but some terminals used to wait for that before they wrote any data...

Comment: @mgilson is correct, it's fairly easy to make a grid of plots using `multiplot layout x,y`.  Also in my script (I'm using 4.7) it plotted fine without `unset multiplot`, but I agree that is best practice, so I'll add it in.

Comment: @andyras -- Like I said, the behavior of your script if you don't have `unset multiplot` used to be *terminal* dependent, not (necessarily) *gnuplot version* dependent.